# Move title "meta box" in post mode

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I've created a custom post type with my own custom meta boxes.
Now I want to move the title box to the side or simply remove it and place the same content in a custom meta box.

How do I go about to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your post type, use the `supports` argument to explicitly set which core meta boxes to use.

```
register_post_type('my_type', array(
    'supports' => array( 'editor' ) // if "title" isn't in this array, it won't appear on the edit post page
    // other arguments
));
```

Comment: Jeez, sorry, forgot about that. Guess I was just thinking of moving the title box to the place I wanted it.